# Apache и Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache

Как ловить запросы к Веб-серверу на Apache с помощью Пайтона? И как обрабатывать запросы и отправлять ответ?

Comment: mod_wsgi? . . .

Comment: А как-то более подробно о задаче которая перед Вами стоит можете рассказать? А то складывается впечатление, что Вы пытаетесь чесать левой пяткой правое ухо. Первое что Вам хочется посоветовать это fast_api (но это немного по другому работает)